# Create an object from an object with keys with dots

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have an input like :

```js
{
survey.subObject1.key1: true,
survey.subObject1.key2: "OTHER",
survey.subObject2.key3: "[1,2]",
survey.subObject2.key4: false,
survey2.subObject3.key5: false,
survey2.subObject3.key6: false
}
```

And I want to transform it to an object like:

```js
{
  survey: {
    subObject1 : {
      key1: true,
      key2: "OTHER"
    },
    subObject2 : {
      key3: "[1,2]",
      key4: false
    }
  },
  survey2: {
    subObject3 : {
      key5: false,
      key6: false
    }
  }
}
```

For now, I'm able to stringily the keys and have a for, but I don't have any ideas how to recreate the object after :

```js
const x = {
"survey.subObject1.key1": true,
"survey.subObject1.key2": "OTHER",
"survey.subObject2.key3": "[1,2]",
"survey.subObject2.key4": false,
"survey2.subObject3.key5": false,
"survey2.subObject3.key6": false
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(x)) {
      console.log(key)
      console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution that I foud is using https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-object, then you can have:

```
const x = {
"survey.subObject1.key1": true,
"survey.subObject1.key2": "OTHER",
"survey.subObject2.key3": "[1,2]",
"survey.subObject2.key4": false,
"survey2.subObject3.key5": false,
"survey2.subObject3.key6": false
}
//transform to an object 
const y = dot.object(x)

//get back to dot structure
const z = dot.dot(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not pretty, but it works!

Basically, use `reduce` over the `Object.entries` and accumulate the objects using the spead (`...`) operator.

```js
const x = {
"survey.subObject1.key1": true,
"survey.subObject1.key2": "OTHER",
"survey.subObject2.key3": "[1,2]",
"survey.subObject2.key4": false,
"survey2.subObject3.key5": false,
"survey2.subObject3.key6": false
}

const result = Object.entries(x).reduce( (acc,entry) => {
   const [key1,key2,key3] = entry[0].split('.');
   return {
      ...acc, 
      [key1]: {
         ...acc[key1], 
         [key2]:{
            ...(acc[key1]?acc[key1][key2]:{}), 
            [key3]:entry[1]
         }
      }
   };
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem with this solution is that I cannot go deeper or I need to provide the exact number of key, I found an interesting solution using https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-object